# copy local file to remote server in ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, copy

I have to copy a file named thefilethefilethefile.txt from my local machine to the root of my remote server (I have to do this to prove I own the server).

Jeez, where's Windows drag and drop when you need it. How can I achieve this simple task?

In Ubuntu Terminal I have the prompt:

```
metheuser@metheuser-HP-Pavilion-g6:~$
```

I make it:

```
metheuser@metheuser-HP-Pavilion-g6:~$ cp thefilethefilethefile.txt  theserver@theserver.com
```

hit ENTER and all I get is the prompt again : `metheuser@metheuser-HP-Pavilion-g6:~$`

Then I log into `theserver@theserver.com` and the file isn't in the root directory.

I also tried :

```
scp thefilethefilethefile.txt theserver@theserver.com
```

to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a : at the end of the hostname in scp

It works that way, as in :

scp thefilethefilethefile.txt theserver@theserver.com: